# Dropbox fail in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, software-center, root, dropbox

I tried installing Dropbox in Ubuntu 12.04 in the computer that is provided by my university. I do not have root privileges. I tried to install it through Ubuntu Software Center. When I did a reboot this I have this dialogue:

[image: dropbox asking for sudo pass]

The problem is that even if I press cancel, that process that is taking one whole CPU continues (see that in the image above as well). Any solution I see here about this problem implies using sudo password, which, I repeat, I do not have.

If I try to uninstall dropbox from Ubuntu Software Center that action remains waiting, because there is another action in progress: "Searching. Applying changes"

Is there possibility to achieve this without having to use `sudo`?

Comment: I was never able to install it successfully in 12.04 but works fine for me in 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

You want to kill a process owned as root without sudo.

This is impossible - either you are super user or have sudo powers, or you aren't.  If you aren't then you have to either let it finish the process... or do the much more evil option and shut off the system.

If a shutdown won't work then a power off will - you can damage the filesystem this way but the process *will* die - either with the power off of the "halt all remaining processes"  during shutdown.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear, but right now I only want to free that CPU constantly in use... I cannot kill that root process not being root, and I need to do it somehow.

Comment: run from terminal `kill -9 PID` to find the PID run `ps aux | grep ProcessName`

Comment: I tried that before... It doesn't work without sudo. These are the processes:

root      2488  0.0  0.0   4396   524 pts/0    SN+  09:38   0:00 /bin/sh /var/lib/dpkg/info/nautilus-dropbox.postinst configure 
root      2489 98.9  3.8 130736 78620 pts/0    RN+  09:38  74:45 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/dropbox update

They are root...

Comment: Reboot the system - since you don't have sudo you can't stop the process so you have to otherwise force all process death - shutoff.

Comment: Answer rewritten

Comment: I did it. Several times.... And again the same dialogue appears every time!

Comment: @user2427894 Disable dropbox in your startup applications.  Or tell the system admins that you broke it